# append text on "print repeated values" property

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a multiple column report .. The problem i am facing is ..

I have a field marked "Print repeated values" ..

But i would like to append text to it when it repeats itself on column switch or detail overflow or any other reason that might cause it to print again ..

e.g

```
Example 1:
Columnn1 - Field1 text : Header
Columnn2 - Field1 text (repeat) : Header (cont)

Example 2:
Columnn1 - Field1 text : Header
Columnn2 - Field1 text (repeat) : Header A
Columnn3 - Field1 text (repeat) : Header B
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how your datasource is constructed what is in it? Create a [mcve]

Comment: @PetterFriberg This question is not for assistance in code .. rather properties of ireport of jasper report .. if a band/header is displayed twice i would like to show a key which marks its continuation ..

Comment: Print repeated values only indicates that if column value is the same it should be displayed, you will probably need code (variabile) to achieve what you need, which still remains unclear to me.